# Cannot use Essentia.TempoCNN

Tags: python, audio, metadata

I use Python 3.8.10 in Google Colab. I am trying to extract tempo feature using Essentia TempoCNN.

As for first try I used an example code from https://essentia.upf.edu/essentia_python_examples.html (I have loaded model, library and changed filename to my path)

```
import essentia.standard as es

sr = 11025
audio_11khz = es.MonoLoader(filename='my/path.wav', sampleRate=sr)()

global_bpm, local_bpm, local_probs = es.TempoCNN(graphFilename='deeptemp-k16-3.pb')(audio_11khz)

print('song BPM: {}'.format(global_bpm))
```

After executing this code a message pops up
`module 'essentia.standard' has no attribute 'TempoCNN'`
Other Essentia's modules like PercivalBpmEstimator and RhythmExtractor2013 are working well with no issues.

I tried to find some other not Standard versions of Essentia and some information about where exactly is TempoCNN located and how to use it – I found nothing.

Can you provide any example of what exactly should I write to use TempoCNN?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like TempoCNN is only available as a separated library ([PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/tempocnn/), [GitHub](https://github.com/hendriks73/tempo-cnn)).
It can be installed with `pip install tempocnn`.
Both tempocnn-0.0.6 and tempocnn-0.0.5 require tesorflow 1.15.4 so it is no longer compatible with Google Colab.